# best way to cheat - cheat day? cheat meal?

Tags: diet, strength-training

I'm on a strict diet which consists of 3000 calories 50/30/20 (pcf) consisting of chicken or beef, green vegetables, eggs, bread, and rice.

I'm 5'7" and currently about 8% body fat. I have consistently been loosing fat and gaining muscle and I've been happy with my progress.

Is it better to polish off a tub of icecream in one sitting or across a cheat day? Is there any evidence that a cheat day is good for you? I've heard stuff that it keeps your metabolism ticking over or something. Is there any truth to this?

Comment: A good answer would be based on this article: http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/in_defense_of_cheat_days but the article is so good, that any answer that doesn't infringe on the article's copyright would be inferior.

Comment: Why would you want to eat the whole tub of ice cream rather than just a few scoops?

Comment: because I do. I'm on no alcohol, and chicken, rice, and vegies day in, day out, now on my 4th month and I'm going nuts.

Comment: Cheat days is God's way of saying that you should enjoy life a bit with your diet.  It significantly increases your leptin levels which give you that "feel good" sensation for a few days.  A full on cheat day MUST be followed by an extremely strict low carb day though.  That is a rule of thumb I follow and it works wonders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm basing my answer entirely off of this article: http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/in_defense_of_cheat_days

### Supposed benefits

- Increased thyroid hormone output
- Increased 24-hour energy expenditure (up to 9% increase in metabolic rate)
- Increased serum leptin levels (increased thermogenisis)

### Counter-points

- You're probably not leptin-depleted, and your metabolic rate probably hasn't actually slowed significantly.
- Cheat days may be a gateway to full-on failure to follow your planned diet.
- Cheat days will encourage eating of unhealthy foods.

### Counter-counter-points

- If you're not leptin depleted, you aren't dieting hard enough on non-cheat days, and even if you have a slight decrease in metabolism due to caloric deficit, this should be fought by cheat days.
- Not everyone is addicted to food. A cheat day doesn't necessarily mean the end of your diet.
- Cheat days just mean high calories, not bad calories... it's up to you to still eat healthy on a cheat day.

### How to cheat

- Decide that you need to. If your progress has slowed for a few weeks (you say that yours hasn't), try a cheat. If your caloric deficit is not that low, then you don't need to cheat that often.
- **Start with cheat meals. If they are not enough to stimulate progress, progress to cheat days.**
- Don't stuff yourself.